# How to update item quantity in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I don't know much about Excel or spread sheets to be honest. But my girlfriend has been working on updating item quantities for the past two days. There are over 500 items.

Basically what she needs is to type the item name, then have it set every occurrence of that items quantity to the new number.

For example: [bags][8] needs to be changed to 7, so every occurrence where there's `bags` it needs to change its quantity to 7 to look like [bags][7].

If more information is needed please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT:

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

As can be seen in the image `FE871251010` is circled. She needs to be able to
type `FE871251010` in and have `15` beside it replaced with a new number. However, `FE871251010` occurs multiple times and not always under `R1K2`.

Comment: Yes, I think more information is needed. It's not clear to me what it is you want to do.

Comment: @Blackwood I updated my question.

Comment: Is there any chance to get a screenshot, not a photo? You've described your girlfriend is doing her job,  it's fine,  where is the problem? What improvement do toy expect? Why nor your girlfriend asks the question who actually knows the problem itself?

Comment: [Here is how](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-any-version-of-windows/) to take a screenshot. If you add the link, someone will make it appear inline in your question, like n8te did for the photo.

Comment: First part of your question is not justifying your need and even for the second part you have not specified the number to replace existing one. So better be specific and loud, so that others could understand your need and answer.

Comment: This is what references are for. Why not have a unique list in another sheet and simply reference them from the one in the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dave's idea is a good one; you can use references to update your values.

In your photo, Sheet1 is the worksheet being used. Let's assume Sheet2 is blank. (If it's not, just create a new sheet; Sheet4, or New, or whatever you want to name it.) On Sheet2, type each item from Sheet1 into column A. Beside each item, in column B, type the quantity for that item. (This will take a while to set up, but will be very easy to update once you've done it.

Once you have every item and quantity listed in Sheet2, go back to Sheet1. Delete each number next to the items, and replace it with a reference to the cell in Sheet2 that holds that value.

For example, replace the `2` in cell AU2 with the reference for whichever cell is next to "EE3032 1010" in Sheet2. Assuming the corresponding cell in Sheet2 is B2, what you'd type into cell AU2 would look like this:

```
=Sheet2!B2
```

Cell AU2 would populate with the value of cell B2 from Sheet2, and every time you change B2's value, AU2 would automatically update.

Like I said above, this will take some time for initial setup. But the payoff in the long run for time saved will be substantial.